# Reordering of Kendo UI Grid columns based on the order of a list of elements

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

Good day,

I have a list which is having elements, based on that list the grid will be obtained. I've a requirement of changing the order of elements in that list. So when i change the order of list and run the report, the grid is obtaining with the order of before list but not with the newly changed order.

Here is the list:

```
@Html.ListBox("multiselect_to", Model.AvailableColumnsList, new { @class = "form-control bdr_rad_3", size = "8", multiple = "multiple" })
```

Here is the Kendo Grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Entrada.CustomerPortal.UI.Models.JobReport>()
.Name("JobReportGrid")
  .ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf())
  .Pdf(pdf => pdf
  .AllPages()
  .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf")
  .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "JobReports")))
  .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
  .Excel(excel => excel
  .AllPages(true)
  .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
  .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "JobReports")))
  .ColumnMenu()
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(p => p.JobNumber)//.Title("Job <br/> Number")
        .Width(colWidth["Job Number"])
        .ClientTemplate("<a class='jobReportGridJN' jnum='#=JobNumber#'>" + "#=JobNumber#" + "</a>"+
    @" #if(STAT== true) {#  <span><img src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/stat-icon.png") + "'> </span>#}#");

    columns.Bound(p => p.DictatorID);
    columns.Bound(p => p.JobType);//.Title("Job <br/> Type");
    columns.Bound(p => p.DeviceGenerated)//.Title("Device <br/> Generated")
        .Width(colWidth["Device Generated"]);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AppointmentDate)//.Title("Appointment <br/> Date")
        .Width(colWidth["Appointment Date"])
        .Format(colFormat["Appointment Date"]);
    columns.Bound(p => p.InProcess)//.Title("In <br/> Process")
        .Width(colWidth["In Process"])
        .Format(colFormat["In Process"]);
    columns.Bound(p => p.EditingComplete)
        .Width(colWidth["Editing Complete"])
        .Format(colFormat["Editing Complete"]);
    columns.Bound(p => p.JobStatus);//.Title("Job <br/> Status");
    columns.Bound(p => p.MRN);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Patient);
  })
  .Groupable()
  .Selectable(selectable => selectable
  .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
  .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read
        .Action("JobSearchPaginationGrid", "JobReports")
        .Data("residentsReadData"))
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .PageSize((int)ViewData["PageSize"])
    .Group(group => group.Add<string>((string)TempData["GridGroupBy"]))
    .ServerOperation(true)
    )
  .Pageable(pager => pager.Messages(Info => Info.Empty("No Results Found")))
  .Sortable()
  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
  .Scrollable().Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
)
```

[Image for Kendo UI grid columns before changing the order of list of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS3yu.png)

[Image for List after changing the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO3eR.png)

So, Can i reorder the Grid columns based on that list elements after changing the order of list?

It would be more helpful, if anyone answer quickly.

Thanks,

Sai

Comment: I think http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns will be helpful.

Comment: I think it's about grouping the Kendo grid data. 

My requirement is not about grouping the grid data.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself but after a minute of googling there seems to be 2 steps involved in the process of achieving this if I understand it correctly:

1. First you have to set `Reorderable` to true for the grid:

   ```
   .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
   ```

   http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/column-reordering
2. Reordering the columns programmatically at list change event:

   ```
   var grid = $("#JobReportGrid").data("kendoGrid");
   grid.reorderColumn(newOrderIndex, grid.columns[currentIndex]);
   ```

   http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-reorderColumn